Why when i try to upgrade flutter sdk version in idx, the emulator gets error
First i'm trying to change the dart version in pubpec.yaml
sdk: '>=3.5.0 <4.0.0'

After that i'm change the package in dev.nix flutter package
channel = "unstable"; # or "unstable"
  # Use https://search.nixos.org/packages to find packages
  packages = [
    pkgs.flutter
    pkgs.nodePackages.firebase-tools
    pkgs.jdk17
    pkgs.unzip
  ];

And this the error
<IDX> ✘ Preview failed to start
2024-10-02T03:35:38Z [android] <IDX> Starting preview...
2024-10-02T03:35:38Z [web] <IDX> Starting preview...
2024-10-02T03:35:38Z [android] Flutter daemon started
2024-10-02T03:35:38Z [web] Flutter daemon started
2024-10-02T03:35:38Z [android] No supported devices found with name or id matching 'localhost:5555'.
2024-10-02T03:35:38Z [android] The following devices were found:
2024-10-02T03:35:39Z [android] Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
2024-10-02T03:35:39Z [android] Linux (desktop)                    • linux         • linux-x64   • IDX GNU/Linux 6.1.100+
2024-10-02T03:35:39Z [android] <IDX> ✘ Preview failed to start
2024-10-02T03:35:40Z [web] Launching lib/main.dart on Web Server in debug mode...
2024-10-02T03:35:40Z [web] Error: 
2024-10-02T03:35:40Z [web] 
2024-10-02T03:35:40Z [web] Error: Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Null check operator used on a null value".
2024-10-02T03:35:40Z [web] 
2024-10-02T03:35:47Z [web] Error: A crash report has been written to /home/user/myapp/flutter_05.log
2024-10-02T03:35:47Z [web] 
2024-10-02T03:35:47Z [web] This crash may already be reported. Check GitHub for similar crashes.
2024-10-02T03:35:47Z [web] https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Null+check+operator+used+on+a+null+value
2024-10-02T03:35:47Z [web] To report your crash to the Flutter team, first read the guide to filing a bug.
2024-10-02T03:35:47Z [web] https://flutter.dev/to/report-bugs
2024-10-02T03:35:47Z [web] Create a new GitHub issue by pasting this link into your browser and completing the issue template. Thank you!
2024-10-02T03:35:47Z [web] https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?title=%5Btool_crash%5D+_TypeError%3A+%28%230++++++currentPackageConfig+%28package%3Aflutter_tools%2Fsrc%2Fdart%2Fpackage_map.dart%3A16%3A56%29%29&body=%23%23+Command%0A%60%60%60sh%0Aflutter+run+--machine+-d+web-server+--web-hostname+0.0.0.0+--web-port+9002%0A%60%60%60%0A%0A%23%23+Steps+to+Reproduce%0A1.+...%0A2.+...%0A3.+...%0A%0A%23%23+Logs%0A_TypeError%3A+%28%230++++++currentPackageConfig+%28package%3Aflutter_tools%2Fsrc%2Fdart%2Fpackage_map.dart%3A16%3A56%29%29%0A%60%60%60console%0A%230++++++currentPackageConfig+%28package%3Aflutter_tools%2Fsrc%2Fdart%2Fpackage_map.dart%3A16%3A56%29%0A%231++++++_loadDwdsDirectory+%28package%3Aflutter_tools%2Fsrc%2Fisolated%2Fdevfs_web.dart%3A1234%3A45%29%0A%232++++++WebAssetServer.start+%28package%3Aflutter_tools%2Fsrc%2Fisolated%2Fdevfs_web.dart%3A270%3A15%29%0A%3Casynchronous+suspension%3E%0A%233++++++WebDevFS.create+%28package%3Aflutter_tools%2Fsrc%2Fisolated%2Fdevfs_web.dart%3A860%3A22%29%0A%3Casynchronous+suspension%3E%0A%234++++++ResidentWebRunner.run.%3Canonymous+closure%3E+%28package%3Aflutter_tools%2Fsrc%2Fisolated%2Fresident_web_runner.dart%3A328%3A19%29%0A%3Casynchronous+suspension%3E%0A%235++++++asyncGuard.%3Canonymous+closure%3E+%28package%3Aflutter_tools%2Fsrc%2Fbase%2Fasync_guard.dart%3A111%3A24%29%0A%3Casynchronous+suspension%3E%0A%60%60%60%0A%60%60%60console%0A%5B%E2%9C%93%5D+Flutter+%28Channel+stable%2C+3.24.1%2C+on+IDX+GNU%2FLinux+6.1.100%2B%2C+locale+en_US%29%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Flutter+version+3.24.1+on+channel+stable+at+%2Fnix%2Fstore%2Fivslg1wbqmfcfhaxabdi36bd3cjvhnbq-flutter-wrapped-3.24.1-sdk-links%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Upstream+repository+https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fflutter%2Fflutter.git%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Framework+revision+nixpkgs000+%28%29%2C+1970-01-01+00%3A00%3A00%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Engine+revision+c9b9d5780d%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Dart+version+3.5.1%0A++++%E2%80%A2+DevTools+version+2.37.2%0A%0A%5B%21%5D+Android+toolchain+-+develop+for+Android+devices+%28Android+SDK+version+30.0.3%29%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Android+SDK+at+%2Fopt%2Fandroid%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Platform+android-34%2C+build-tools+30.0.3%0A++++%E2%80%A2+ANDROID_SDK_ROOT+%3D+%2Fopt%2Fandroid%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Java+binary+at%3A+%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fjava%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Java+version+OpenJDK+Runtime+Environment+%28build+17.0.11%2B9-nixos%29%0A++++%21+Some+Android+licenses+not+accepted.+To+resolve+this%2C+run%3A+flutter+doctor+--android-licenses%0A%0A%5B%E2%9C%97%5D+Chrome+-+develop+for+the+web+%28Cannot+find+Chrome+executable+at+google-chrome%29%0A++++%21+Cannot+find+Chrome.+Try+setting+CHROME_EXECUTABLE+to+a+Chrome+executable.%0A%0A%5B%E2%9C%93%5D+Linux+toolchain+-+develop+for+Linux+desktop%0A++++%E2%80%A2+clang+version+18.1.8%0A++++%E2%80%A2+cmake+version+3.29.6%0A++++%E2%80%A2+ninja+version+1.12.1%0A++++%E2%80%A2+pkg-config+version+0.29.2%0A%0A%5B%21%5D+Android+Studio+%28not+installed%29%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Android+Studio+not+found%3B+download+from+https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fstudio%2Findex.html%0A++++++%28or+visit+https%3A%2F%2Fflutter.dev%2Fto%2Flinux-android-setup+for+detailed+instructions%29.%0A%0A%5B%E2%9C%93%5D+Connected+device+%283+available%29%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Android+SDK+built+for+x86+%28mobile%29+%E2%80%A2+emulator-5554+%E2%80%A2+android-x86++++%E2%80%A2+Android+10+%28API+29%29+%28emulator%29%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Linux+%28desktop%29++++++++++++++++++++%E2%80%A2+linux+++++++++%E2%80%A2+linux-x64++++++%E2%80%A2+IDX+GNU%2FLinux+6.1.100%2B%0A++++%E2%80%A2+Web+Server+%28web%29+++++++++++++++++++%E2%80%A2+web-server++++%E2%80%A2+web-javascript+%E2%80%A2+Flutter+Tools%0A%0A%5B%E2%9C%93%5D+Network+resources%0A++++%E2%80%A2+All+expected+network+resources+are+available.%0A%0A%21+Doctor+found+issues+in+3+categories.%0A%0A%60%60%60%0A%0A%23%23+Flutter+Application+Metadata%0A%2A%2AType%2A%2A%3A+app%0A%2A%2AVersion%2A%2A%3A+1.0.0%2B1%0A%2A%2AMaterial%2A%2A%3A+true%0A%2A%2AAndroid+X%2A%2A%3A+false%0A%2A%2AModule%2A%2A%3A+false%0A%2A%2APlugin%2A%2A%3A+false%0A%2A%2AAndroid+package%2A%2A%3A+null%0A%2A%2AiOS+bundle+identifier%2A%2A%3A+null%0A%2A%2ACreation+channel%2A%2A%3A+stable%0A%2A%2ACreation+framework+version%2A%2A%3A+761747bfc538b5af34aa0d3fac380f1bc331ec49%0A%0A&labels=tool%2Csevere%3A+crash
2024-10-02T03:35:47Z [web] <IDX> ✘ Preview failed to start

I expect the emulator can running and try new feature in flutter
